# WSO2DSS 3.2.2 call two queries from one operation

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I want call two queries in one operation and get the result. In 3.1.1 version I use  but in new version it not work. any solution for this ?

this is what i use earlier

```
<call-query-group>
         <call-query href="OnBoardingCheckList_Query">
            <with-param name="partyid" query-param="partyid"/>
            <with-param name="loginName" query-param="loginName"/>
         </call-query>
         <call-query href="ManagemetPortal_query" requiredRoles="">
            <with-param name="loginName" query-param="loginName"/>
         </call-query>
      </call-query-group>
```

unfortunately this is not working in wso2dss 3.2.2

Cheers!
Chathura

Comment: I know this question has been posted quite a long time ago, but I faced the same problem and came up with a hack of sorts in order to address this kind of situation, using nested queries in order to achieve our goal.

The outer query can be a dummy one, say a "select 1 from dual" or somethig like that. The point is that will create a single result which can then be enriched by nested calls.

Comment: This feature is removed from the latest  version of the DSS server

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with older versions but I think what you are looking to do is invoke two queries and return one result. A challenge is how do you handle the situation where the results of each query have differing schema?

If you are updating values in one or both of the quesries then you should look into 'boxcaring'.

If you are just reading from botth queries then read on...

I have previously handled this using WSO2 ESB along with WSO2 DSS.

1. Essentially setup your two DSS operations.
2. Configure ESB to invoke the DSS operations and aggregate the DSS responses into a single result.
3. Publish the ESB service, not the two DSS operations

You can read more here. http://dakshithar.blogspot.ca/2014/05/entity-aggregation-with-wso2-esb-and_14.html

Also if for development purposes you need to run both DSS and ESB on a single machine you will need to set the Port Offset of one of the deployments so they can run side-by-side on the machine (no conflict). You can choose to change Port Offset either DSS or ESB, it oes not matter. I usually change the offset of the last one I installed.

**To set Port Offset**

Port Offset can be set in the /repository/conf/carbon.xml file in the ESB or DSS binary distribution folder. Set the offset value as 1